# using free database coolprop in my c# program

Tags: c#, wrapper

I would like to use the following in my program, so i can use it's functions:
http://www.coolprop.org/coolprop/wrappers/Csharp/index.html
However i have no idea how to do the things explained in the link above.

I was able to instal the third-party nuget. But i would like to use the original CoolProp and it's functions rather. So i was looking at the "pre-compiled binaries" and "user-compiled binaries" but can't seem to figure it out... I have zero experience in this and have been looking all over the internet for some tutorials etc. without any luck.

basicaly i followed the following:
[coolprop explenation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0DZ4.png)
so i do this:
[developer comand promt input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDjhs.png)
and get this result:
[devoloper command prompt result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b3s5.png)

Ran command seperate, first line is ok i think, second throws errors:
[separeted lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhHPg.png)

folder where i stored the files:
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kADQN.png)

I hope someone here can help me, thanks in advance.

greetings

Matti

Comment: Can you clearly explain the problem? What step are you doing and what is happening?

Comment: CoolProp isn't even a database, it's a library to calculate a bunch of fluid stuff

Comment: @Sinatr i made an edit on my post, is this what you meant?

Comment: @MindSwipe i know it's used to calculate fluid properties, that it is a library and not a database is my mistake in writing/knowledge.

Comment: In guide those 3 lines are 3 separate commands (you have to enter one line and hit enter) and you are trying to enter them as one.

Comment: @sinatr i ran them separate now, did an edit on my past to show the result. First line i got working i think. Second one shows errors.

Comment: Did you extract the .7z file to that folder as per the instructions

Comment: @Milney i added a picture off the folder in my post above just now.